# Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type

Tags: angular

I am building an angular 4 component and writing a service to return a resultset. I am getting a compile error in the movie component in the code where its trying to call the movieservice. The error is in the getMovies method in movie component. Not sure what the problem is

The error states Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type IMovie[].

Below is the code

**IMovie interface**

```
export interface IMovie{
    movieId:number;
    name:string;
    actor:string;
    director:string;
    movieLength:number;  
}
```

**Movie service**

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {MRDBCommonService} from '../shared/services/mrdb.common.service';
import {IMovie} from './movie.interface';
const URL_MOVIE = '/api/movie';

@Injectable()
export class MovieService 
{

constructor(private _mrdbCommonService: MRDBCommonService){}

    getMovies() : IMovie[] {
        return[
         {
            movieId:1,
            name:"Titanic",
            actor:"Test1",
            director:"Test2",
            movieLength : 2 
         },
         {
            movieId:2,
            name:"Titanic",
            actor:"Test1",
            director:"Test2",
            movieLength:2 
         },
         {
            movieId:3,
            name:"Titanic",
            actor:"Test1",
            director:"Test2",
            movieLength: 2 
         }
        ];
    }
}
```

**Movie component**

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {MovieService} from './movie.service';
import {IMovie} from './movie.interface';


@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'app-movie',
  templateUrl: './movie.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./movie.component.css'],
  providers:[MovieService]
})

export class MovieComponent implements OnInit {

public movieList : IMovie = null;

  constructor(private movieSerice : MovieService) {
    this.getMovies();
   }

  ngOnInit() {

  }

  private getMovies()
  {
    this.movieSerice.getMovies().subscribe((result : IMovie) => {

    this.movieList = result;
    });

  }

}
```

Comment: Well why *did* you `.subscribe`? That method just returns an array, not an observable, *as you've typed and written it*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are returning the array of movie list of type IMovie, some correction you need, 
**As you are not returning Observable but you are trying to subscribe that's why you are getting error .**

**Movie component**

### as you are receiving the collection of IMovie type object so your movieList variable should be the array of IMovie.

```
public movieList : IMovie[]
```

### Your service should like this -

```
import {Observable} from "rxjs";// First you need to import Observable
```

Then you should return Observable type data from your getMovies method. Now your method should look like this

```
getMovies(): Observable<IMovie[]> {

        return Observable.of([
        {
            movieId: 1,
            name: "Titanic",
            actor: "Test1",
            director: "Test2",
            movieLength: 2
        },
        {
            movieId: 2,
            name: "Titanic",
            actor: "Test1",
            director: "Test2",
            movieLength: 2
        },
        {
            movieId: 3,
            name: "Titanic",
            actor: "Test1",
            director: "Test2",
            movieLength: 2
        }
    ]);
    }
```

### I think it will works fine and u can ask anything if you have any query, Happy Coding

Answer (score 2):

Your `getMovies()` does not return an `Observable` type, hence can't be subscribed. You need to wrap it with `Observable.of()`:

```
getMovies(): Observable<IMovie[]> {
    return Observable.of([
        {
            movieId: 1,
            name: "Titanic",
            actor: "Test1",
            director: "Test2",
            movieLength: 2
        },
        {
            movieId: 2,
            name: "Titanic",
            actor: "Test1",
            director: "Test2",
            movieLength: 2
        },
        {
            movieId: 3,
            name: "Titanic",
            actor: "Test1",
            director: "Test2",
            movieLength: 2
        }
    ]);
}
```

Comment: @Aravind How is this duplicate of yours when I **explicitly** wrote the code that he should return an Observable using `Observable.of()`. But if downvote makes you feel better, go ahead.