# Removing data in array also remove data in Observable

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

I am trying to get data from Observable and move it to an array. then I would like to try to splice 1 item in the array, but somehow the item inside the observable is also removed. is there anything that I did wrong?

assume this is the value of my observable data:

```
dataObs = {
   values:[{id: 1, name: orange},
           {id: 2, name: apple},
           {id: 3, name: peach}], ...}
```

Here is my code

```
        let dataArr = new Array<any>;

        this.dataObs.subscribe(val => dataArr = val);
        dataArr.forEach((element, index) => {
           if(element.id == 1) dataArr.splice(index, 1) //delete orange in the array
           });
```

somehow, the orange in observable also deleted.

```
dataObs = {
   values:[{id: 2, name: apple},
           {id: 3, name: peach}], ...}
```

Comment: Part of the has error. Can you check and debug (Probably you made a mistake when you copied to code)?

Comment: Hi @AliBektash I just update my question to make it clearer. Also, the code works fine, but maybe there is some incorrect logic that I apply.

Thanks for your response!

Answer (score 0):

You can use subscribe function for only **Observable** (and dataObs object has no subscribe function). You can look over this page.

[Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44868458/property-subscribe-does-not-exist-on-type)